# Automatically dispatching single-case inductive types

Tags: coq, ltac

I'm trying to learn how to do Coq proof automation à la Chlipala/`crush`. To this end I wonder what's a convenient approach for automatically breaking down single-case inductive types, for example when solving the following:

```
Goal forall {A B: Prop}, (A <-> B) -> (A -> B).
Goal forall {A B: Type}, A * B -> A.
```

I'd like to automatically break these down *only when it makes sense* - that is, only when I don't lose any information by doing so. Is that possible?

Comment: Incidentally, if you are interested in alternatives to this approach, you could take a peek at e.g. https://github.com/coq-community/lemma-overloading

Comment: SSReflect offers the `Hint View` mechanism, so that, for instance, one could use equivalences when an implication is needed (unfortunately it does not work everywhere at the moment, e.g. the `rewrite` tactic does not use it). Also, in some cases the mechanism of implicit *coercions* can take care of this.